# Is it a mandatory to add payable keyword when using msg.value

Tags: solidity

Example :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract X{

    uint amount;

    function X() {
        amount = amount + msg.value;
    }
}
```

Here Constructor X() is not payable. Should I change it to payable because of using msg.value ?

Comment: Yes, I think this was changed in Solidity 0.4.x

Comment: No, it's not mandatory, but it will always be 0, because the contract will throw an exception if there is any value sent with it.

Comment: What will always be zero? The amount, or msg.value? @TjadenHess

Comment: Both. `msg.value`  will always be zero, because any nonzero value will cause an error.  `ammount` will be zero because it is impossible to add anything to it

Answer (score 2):

Not mandatory, but as Matthew notes, it would be useless to leave it out of the function that should be receiving ether.

`msg.value` gets passed around internally.

Browser Solidity is aware that we don't have a problem in the code below. It's not warning about the presence of `msg.value` inside a function that itself isn't payable.

If the `logValue()` function is changed to `public`, then Browser Solidity warns that there might be an oversight.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Having just tried it in browser-solidity, it will *warn* you, but it will not stop you.

That said, I'm not sure what use it would have other than calling it through a different, payable function. browser-solidity doesn't have a way to send amounts, it seems. Can anyone test if that works?